# Spring JSR-303 with form:errors tag

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to use `JSR-303` validation and display it's results in `jsp` page. Here is `jsp` page code piece which shows error:

```
<c:set var="Error">
    <form:errors path="name"/>
</c:set>
...
<spring:transform value="${Error}"/>
```

In the controller I have the following:

```
@PostMapping(params = "next")
public String next(@Valid @ModelAttribute(COMMAND_NAME) final ProjectNewDetailsCommand cmd,
                   final Errors errors,
                   final Model model,
                   final HttpServletRequest request) {
```

First, the solution which worked for me is writing a custom `Validator` class:

```
@Override
public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
    errors.pushNestedPath("project");
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "name", "error.project.creation.name.required");
    errors.popNestedPath();
}
```

In this case the appropriate message from `messages.properties` was applied and show on UI:

```
error.project.creation.name.required=The name must not be blank.
```

Here is another case when I use `JSR-303` annotation:

```
public class Project {

    ...
    @Size(max = 100, message = "error.project.creation.size")
    private String name;
```

In `messages.properties` there is the message under key `error.project.creation.size`, I've also tried to add the message with key `Size.command.project.name` as it's stated in some of the sources. `Error` object in controller is also not empty and contains validation errors. But when I use this approach with `JSR-303` I got the following error:

```
Caused by: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'Size' for locale 'en_US'.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.doEndTag(MessageTag.java:200)
```

Which means that for some reason `Spring` tries to apply `Size` error code instead of `error.project.creation.size` or `Size.command.project.name`. Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix this?

Comment: I think it should be written `message = "{error.project.creation.size}"` to match `error.project.creation.size`

Comment: I've tried this as well. Didn't work for me, so I guess there is some other issue.

Comment: Ok, and when you have tried it, what was the content of the Error object? Does the message was present?

Comment: Yes, the key was present in `defaultMessage` field as `{error.project.creation.size}` and error codes where `Size.command.project.name`, `Size.project.name`, `Size.name`, `Size.java.lang.String` and `Size`. And none of them except of `Size` didn't work as a key in `messages.properties` file.

Comment: Ok so your Error object seems fine. In the front do you confirm that your form:errors is in spring:bind? Also maybe the error is not properly map to the form . you can do something like that if your form is called cmd : `redirectModel.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.cmd", result);`

Comment: Yes, exactly, the error is not property mapped to the form. And no, I don't use `spring:bind`, not sure if that is actually needed. As I wrote above, just the same stuff but with custom `Validator` worked for me.

Comment: Does the form:errors is inside the form:form that have the commandName equal to the value of `COMMAND_NAME` (defined in your java)?

Comment: Yes, it's inside `form:form`, the problem is that jsp page tries to use error code instead of `defaultMessage`, as actually `defaultMessage` contains the correct message, but key `Size` is used for lookup instead.

Comment: Basically it should work so not sure why you would need your own implementation (might be due to the use of wrapping it with `c:set` and use `spring:transform`. I suggest to try it without. Which spring version are you using?

Comment: Yes, I'm also wondering why it's not working without it. It's Spring 4.3.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to find the source of the problem. In the code for rendering alerts, there was a `spring:message` tag:

```
<spring:message code="${error.code}" arguments="${error.arguments}"/>
```

If works in the following way: it looks for last code from the `codes` array in `Errors` class (see [DefaultMessageSourceResolvable.getCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.collector/2.0.5/org/springframework/context/support/DefaultMessageSourceResolvable.java#DefaultMessageSourceResolvable.getCode%28%29) method) and that's why it couldn't find `Size` message and didn't picked up `defaultMessage` created by hibernate validator or the custom one.

The simple fix in this case was to add `text` attribute:

```
<spring:message code="${error.code}" arguments="${error.arguments}" text="${error.defaultMessage}"/>
```